# Why do I get multiple contracts when using the standard token code?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens

[image]

When using the standard token code given at https://ethereum.org/token#the-code I notice that I get the option to deploy multiple contracts. By deploying all 3 separately, it does not create the intended effect of creating a token. You can see in the attached screenshot there are three contracts to deploy. The screenshot is from the IDE remix.ethereum.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in short** : you've got this multiple creation inputs because you have many contracts defined in your code due to the inheritance ( parents : `owned, token`). This isn't a problem, you need just deploy the last contract `MyAdvancedToken`(child) the others will be included.